# Execution flow for PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, production-environment, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have many packages in production system and those packages has as much procedures.Say some of them updates/inserts into a table. How can I identify those packages in sequence of operation without going through 1000s lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a possible answer. Is there one single point in the code where all execution starts or does a client application call many different functions in an order outside of the PLSQL scope. 

And even if there were a possible answer. What would this tell you?

Comment: I need to create a plot, so that new joinees can look at it and have an overview.

Comment: Then follow the code.

Comment: Follow the code like Rene said... or Search for all your insert/update statements and above all of them add a console print that telles where the code is: `dbms_output.put_line('Procedure A1 - Query 4');`. Then exec everything and recuperate the console output so you can follow the flow. You have no other option

Comment: Use `DBMS_HPROF`.  After running your code with `DBMS_HPROF` enabled, the `dbmshp_*` tables will tell you which packages called which other packages, how many times, and how long each call took.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: can you please move this from comment to answer, so that we can vote on it :-)